# Query in LINQ with self join

Tags: c#, sql, linq, unit-of-work

I have a table which contains columns among others like Id as Primary Key and LastMeterReadingId (Foreign Key which references to same table) - something like Parent Meter Reading.

[image: That's how it's looks like]

I would like to get all rows which are not already used like Parent. I would like to avoid situation when meter reading is parent for more than one meter reading.

I know how to join to same table, but I have no idea how to choose only those records which aren't parent already. That's how query looks like without condition statement.

```
return (from m in uow.MeterReadingReadWriteRepository.Query()
                join parent in uow.MeterReadingReadWriteRepository.Query() on m.Id equals parent.LastMeterReadingId

                select new MeterReadingDto()
                {
                    (...)
                }).ToList();
```

Do you have any idea how to achieve it in efficient way?

Regards.

Comment: Usually case like this I write a recursive method to enumerate through the table.  Linq is ok for just a parent child joining, but with multiple generations LINQ doesn't give good results.

Comment: Firstly I would argue that this violates normal form. Because isn't whether or not a meter reading is a child of another information that can be obtained simply by sorting by meter read date. Also what happens if you chain them together and someone deletes a record in the middle of a chain. Aren't you a bit screwed in that case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would like to get all rows which are not already used like Parent

In other words, you want all rows that have no children. Note that the variable name `parent` in your query is misleading - when you do `a join b on a.Id equals b.ParentId`, `a` is the parent and `b` is the child.

Anyway, there are at least 3 ways to achieve your goal, IMO being equivalent from nowadays database query optimizers point of view (i.e. should be equally efficient):

(1) Using `!Any(...)` which is equivalent to SQL `NOT EXISTS(...)`:

```
from m in uow.MeterReadingReadWriteRepository.Query()
where !uow.MeterReadingReadWriteRepository.Query().Any(child => m.Id == child.LastMeterReadingId)
select ...
```

(2) Using [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx):

```
from m in uow.MeterReadingReadWriteRepository.Query()
join child in uow.MeterReadingReadWriteRepository.Query()
on m.Id equals child.LastMeterReadingId into children
where !children.Any()
select ...
```

(3) Using left outer antijoin:

```
from m in uow.MeterReadingReadWriteRepository.Query()
join child in uow.MeterReadingReadWriteRepository.Query()
on m.Id equals  child.LastMeterReadingId into children
from child in children.DefaultIfEmpty()
where child == null
select ...
```

If this is EF (LINQ to Entities), the first two are translated to one and the same SQL `NOT EXISTS` based query. While the last is translated to the "traditional" SQL `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE right.PK IS NULL` based query.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add

`where !(from child in uow.MeterReadingReadWriteRepository.Query() where child.Id == m.LastMeterReadingId select child).Any()`

Not sure how intelligently this would be optimised though.  It would also be better to factor out uow.MeterReadingReadWriteRepository.Query().

Do you not have a Child relationship/collection in your Meter Reading entity from the foreign key constraint? - this would make the query much more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

```
var readings = uow.MeterReadingReadWriteRepository.Query();

var parents = readings
        .Join(readings, child => child.Id, parent => parent.LastMeterReadingId,
                (child, parent) => new {parent.Id})
        .Distinct()
        .ToDictionary(a => a.Id);

var result = (from m in readings
                  where !parents.Contains(m.Id) 
                  select new
                    {
                       Id = m.Id
                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ben Jackson

```
public class MeterReading : EntityBase
{
    public long PropertyId { get; set; }
    public long? LastMeterReadingId { get; set; }
    public long? PaymentId { get; set; }
    public Property Property { get; set; }
    public MeterReading LastReading { get; set; }
    public Payment Payment { get; set; }
}
```

That's how most value properties looks like. Maybe should I use T-SQL query with JOIN to CTE which mentioned before condition statement? I'll try your solution ASAP.